# Compiling foundation sass with grunt-sass

Tags: javascript, sass, gruntjs, zurb-foundation

When i compile with **grunt** command all the tasks except **sass** works fine it just output the comments all the **@import** parts inside **foundation.scss** not compiling.

What's the problem ?
This is my gruntfile.js

```
        module.exports = function(grunt) {

    grunt.initConfig({
    pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),
    uglify: {
      build: {
        src: 'src/js/*.js',
        dest: 'js/script.min.js'
      },
      dev:{
        options:{
          beautify: true,
          mangle: false,
          compress:false,
          preserveComments: 'all'
        },
        src: 'src/js/*.js',
        dest: 'js/script.min.js'
      }
    },
    sass: {
      dev:{
        options:{
          outputStyle: 'expanded'
        },
        files:{
          'css/app.css' : 'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss'
        }
      },
      build:{
        options:{
          outputStyle: 'compressed'
        },
        files:{
          'css/app.css' : 'node_modules/foundation-sites/scss'
        }
      }
    },
    watch:{
      js: {
        files: ['src/js/*.js'],
        tasks: ['uglify:dev']
      },
      css: {
        files: ['node_modules/foundation-sites/scss/**/*.scss'],
        tasks: ['sass:dev']
      }
    }
  });
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-uglify');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
  grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-sass');
  // Default task(s).
  grunt.registerTask('default', ['uglify:dev', 'sass:dev']);
  grunt.registerTask('build', ['uglify:build', 'sass:build']);

};
```

and this is my foundation.scss file:

```
/**
 * Foundation for Sites by ZURB
 * Version 6.2.4
 * foundation.zurb.com
 * Licensed under MIT Open Source
 */

// Sass utilities
@import 'util/util';

// Global variables and styles
@import 'global';

// Components
@import 'grid/grid';
@import 'typography/typography';
@import 'forms/forms';
@import 'components/visibility';
@import 'components/float';
@import 'components/button';
@import 'components/button-group';
@import 'components/accordion-menu';
@import 'components/accordion';
@import 'components/badge';
@import 'components/breadcrumbs';
@import 'components/callout';
@import 'components/close-button';
@import 'components/drilldown';
@import 'components/dropdown-menu';
@import 'components/dropdown';
@import 'components/flex';
@import 'components/flex-video';
@import 'components/label';
@import 'components/media-object';
@import 'components/menu';
@import 'components/menu-icon';
@import 'components/off-canvas';
@import 'components/orbit';
@import 'components/pagination';
@import 'components/progress-bar';
@import 'components/reveal';
@import 'components/slider';
@import 'components/sticky';
@import 'components/switch';
```

Answer (score 1):

you should use `foundation watch` to manage the build process, no? read here: http://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/installation.html

Comment: The problem is not the build process itself it works fine but it only output the first 6 comment lines. The other parts @import doesn't compile to css at all.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to import all components of Foundation, as described in the [documentation](https://foundation.zurb.com/sites/docs/sass.html)?

> Each component has an export mixin which prints out the CSS for that
>   component. If you're cool with having everything, you just need one
>   line of code:
>
> ```
> @include foundation-everything;
> ```